Difference between the meaning of hafs and warsh recitation of surah 98 verse 6
Assalam o alaikum! I was watching a video recently where someone pointed out that the hafs and warsh recitations of surah 98 verse 6 have different meaning. In hafs the word for worst of creatures is شَرُّ الْبَرِيَّةِ while in warsh it says شر البريئة the latter translates into worst of innocent. I've checked the translation for بريئة and it translates into innocent. These are neither same nor complimentary. How do you reconcile these two?

Your translation is wrong. Both are different pronunciations and mean the same thing, i.e. creatures.

Can you elaborate. I've checked the translation of the word بريئة online and it translates into innocent. I've checked multiple translation apps and they all give the same meaning. Can you please elaborate or list a source where I can see a detailed explanation of these two recitations translation. I'm genuinely confused and want to understand.

Both recitations are identic its just a deviation of fluency
There's no difference between:

شَرُّ الْبَرِيَّةِ

and

شر البريئة

In fact, these are identic parts of sentences, meaning "worst of creation", not worst of innocence.
The only difference is that strangely Hafs is using the more fluent Arabic word برية without "hamzah", which is generally very heavy for an Arabic speaker (that's why it is regarded as less fluent). Scholars such as Taher ibn 'Ashur in his at-Tahrir wa Tanwir explained that البريئة with the hamzah is part of the language of Quraish and this reading is the reading of Nafi'i and that from ibn Dhkwan from ibn 'Amir, the rest of the 10 qari's and their rawis read it in less heavily like Hafs did. In fact, there are three words in which the people of Hijaz (like the tribe of Quraish) emphasize the hamzah these are:

البريئة
النبيء (the porphet), الأنبئاء, النبيئين
الدَّرِيَّةِ

In today's modern Arabic language usage, the language of Hafs has overrun the fluency and we see excessive usage of hamzahs, I've only heard a few Iranian scholars and some scholars from the Maghreb who may still pronounce a "yaa'" instead of the "hamzah" in similar occasions.
Translation of the meaning
As for translation here is a word-by-word translation:

شر

in Arabic means:

evil, bad etc.

While

برية or بريئة

means creation its plural is بَرايا. It is from the root verb:

برأ

In other words, the "hamzah" is the origin here.
If we say:

برَأ اللهُ الكونَ

where الكونَ refers to the universe.
This sentence means that Allah created the universe.
It is used similarly in the qur'an:

مَا أَصَابَ مِنْ مُصِيبَةٍ فِي الأَرْضِ وَلاَ فِي أَنْفُسِكُمْ إلاَّ فِي كِتَابٍ مِنْ قَبْلِ أَنْ نَبْرَأَهَا ...(57:22)
No misfortune can happen on earth or in your souls but is recorded in a decree before We bring it into existence... (Translation of Yusuf Ali)

The Sahih International translation is a bit focussing on a less expressive meaning.
And the same context one of Allah's names is al-Bari' or al-Bari:

البارئ or الباري

Allah says referring to this name:

هُوَ اللَّهُ الْخَالِقُ الْبَارِئُ الْمُصَوِّرُ ۖ لَهُ الْأَسْمَاءُ الْحُسْنَىٰ ۚ يُسَبِّحُ لَهُ مَا فِي السَّمَاوَاتِ وَالْأَرْضِ ۖ وَهُوَ الْعَزِيزُ الْحَكِيمُ
He is Allah, the Creator, the Inventor, the Fashioner; to Him belong the best names. Whatever is in the heavens and earth is exalting Him. And He is the Exalted in Might, the Wise. (59:24)

Which means the originator or creator. But you may find this option only on the 4th page even on almaany.com if you check the Arabic-English translation.
You may have heard the name of ibn Hajar's great commentary on Sahih al-Bukhari called Fath al-Bari فتح الباري. which literally means "Grant of the Creator".
Your wrong translation
While your wrong translation uses the wrong root, since it recognizes -wrongly-:

بريئة

as the female version of:

بريئ

Which is innocent (plurals masculine:  بَريئون و أبرياء و بُرَآء و بُرَاء و بِرَاء and feminine:  بَريئات).
You cannot rely on an Arabic translation without having at least a bit of linguistic background. Since there are a lot of verbs written:

برأ

Some mean to heal or to recover, others mean to create, others may mean to exculpate and many other meanings. One point to start is checking existing qur'an translations and the context. Further, if you have some basic knowledge of Arabic you should always check an Arabic (-Arabic) dictionary, because translations into other languages are often not that detailed and use more "modern" words.

The extra hamzah is present in warsh and absent from hafs your answer suggests the opposite.

@Harun good point I knew that there were a few occasions where Hafs acted differently one was this surah in both 98:6 and 98:7. I've checked the tafsir my whole explanation is stilltrue only warsh and hafs were mixed up here, I've updated that part.
